# Azure Load Balancer and Custom IP Adress

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-aks

I don't know if this question is asked before or not but I have researched a lot about this and I did not find any adequate answer related to my problem.

I have a Django project on Azure within the Kubernetes cluster.

There is a load balancer within the resource group which makes the communication between my cluster and the outside world.

Also, I have a static public IP address on my load balancer.
I can communicate with my application with this public IP for example:
http://1.2.3.4:8000/

But, I want to change this IP address with the IP address that my company gives me such as http://2.3.4.5:8000/

This IP address(http://2.3.4.5:8000/) has a domain name such as example.com and they want me to set up the environment so that when they search for example.com on the browser, they come across my application and make the communication with that application.

I tried to change the load balancer's IP address manually but I was not able to change it since there is no menu for determining the IP address manually.

Now, I am wondering how can I make this communication on Azure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the public IP in advance or use an existing one.

You just annotate the service inside k8s and azure will spin up a LoadBalancer with your IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup
  name: public-ip-example
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: <YOUR_PUBLIC_IP>
  type: LoadBalancer
```

You can also check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip).